# Animate width of 3 columns so that they always occupy entire space

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple page containing 3 divs within a container like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="mainColumn1" class="bgColumn"></div>
        <div id="mainColumn2" class="bgColumn"></div>
        <div id="mainColumn3" class="bgColumn"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

They are meant to be 3 even columns that occupy entire page. Whenever you hover one of them it expands to 50%, and the others shrink to 25%.

It's hard to explain where the problem is so here's jFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FWcC5/2/

If you move cursor quickly all over the place, you will notice white space appear on the right side. It happens in Firefox. Oddly enough in Chrome it behaves exactly as it should.

I tried using the same thing with flex-grid, which worked but the performance dropped drastically in Chrome.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: happens for me too on firefox 30...  it seems firefox just cant execute the js fast enough, maybe

Comment: can you elaborate on how drastically did the performance drop? have a look at [This](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/FWcC5/9/) fiddle, using flex + no javascript and it works alright in both chrome and firefox...

Comment: It's really choppy when you use large images as backgrounds. I did it pretty much exactly the same way as you.

Comment: well [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/FWcC5/14/) is an improved version using `.animate()` instead of css transition, it improves the performance, there is still a white space in the same place but its much smaller now

Comment: This actually eliminates the white space problem for me completely in Firefox but it's choppy too. I guess I'll go with flex.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what the problem is with Firefox though I tried and can confirm there is an issue, however there is a better and less procedural way of achieving what you're currently doing.

You can shorten your javascript massively to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bgColumn').hover(function(){
        $('.bgColumn').width("25%").not($(this));
        $(this).width("50%");
    });
});
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FWcC5/6/)

Comment: this is not answer, you code if applied does not solve the problem, and by the way, you linked the wrong fiddle

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bgColumn').hover(function(){
        $(this).width('50%');
        $('.bgColumn').not(this).width('25%');
    },
    function(){
        $('.bgColumn').width('33.3%');
    });
});

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div {
    position: relative;
    background-position: center;
}
#mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.bgColumn {
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33.333%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#mainColumn1 {
    background-color: gray;
    float:left;
}
#mainColumn2 {
    background-color: white;
    float:left;
}
#mainColumn3 {
    background-color: black;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: would you like to explain what you did? sticking plain code as an answer does not really help especially when your code doesnt work...

Comment: Using float doesn't solve the problem. The white space now appears to the right of the middle column (it's just invisible, because middle column is white as well).